# For-Loop to quick to present View Controller

Tags: ios, for-loop, uiviewcontroller, passbook

i want to add multiple passbook passes by running through a array with URLs. The problem is that the loop counts faster than the view controller can present.
Here s my code:

```
    NSArray *passURLArray = [NSArray new];
    passURLArray = response;

    for (int i = 0; passURLArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *passURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.de%@", [passURLArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:passURLString]];

        NSError *error;
        PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[pass passURL]];

        PKAddPassesViewController *passVC = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:pass];
        passVC.delegate = self;
        [passVC setDelegate:(id)self];
        [self presentViewController:passVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

I get this error message:

> Attempt to present PKAddPassesViewController: 0xca5f7d0 on
>   PaymentViewController: 0x14882290 which is waiting for a delayed
>   presention of PKAddPassesViewController: 0xb169470 to complete

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to change to animated:NO instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you're on the last iteration of the loop. If you are, animate the display, if not, don't animate it.

That said, it's nasty from a user standpoint. You should probably think about a nicer way of presenting, like showing a list or animating between each display when `addPassesViewControllerDidFinish:` is called.

Comment: yeah, i think you re right. thought easy and fast will do it, but maybe this doesn t work here.